# Find the number of $6$-digit codes with distinct digits that can be formed if there is more than one odd digit and all odd digits are separated.

Tags: combinatorics

> A $6$-digit code is to be formed using the digits $1$ to $9$ and no digit may appear more than once. Find the number of $6$-digit codes that can be formed if there is more than $1$ odd digit and all odd digits are separated.

My approach:

There are $5$ odd numbers from digits $1$ to $9$.

Consider two cases.

Case 1: With $2$ odd numbers that are separated. There are $10$ ways to arrange the two odd numbers with them separated.

Therefore, there are $5P2 \cdot 4P4 \cdot 10 = 4800$ ways.

Case 2: With $3$ odd numbers that are separated. There are $4$ ways to arrange the $3$ odd numbers with them separated.

Therefore, there are $5P3 \cdot 4P3 \cdot 4 = 5760$ ways.

Total number of ways $= 4800 + 5760 = 10560$.

I would like to ask if there is any easier way to solve this? If so how can I go about doing it?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your solution is correct and efficient.